# grails access form attributes in controller

Tags: forms, grails, attributes

In grails i have a form with g:field tags like:

```
 <g:field name="test" from="0..20"/>
```

I am trying to find a way how I can access the "from" attribute in my controller.
I can get the "value" attribute by using:

```
 print params.test
```

I have tried:

```
 print params.test.from
```

I'm sure there must be a way to do this but I can not seem to find it.

What I am wanting to achieve by this is perform validation so that the value does not go outside the the from range.
I know that this can be added in the domain, but in my situation I need to allow the user to overwrite the range constraints.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the *"from"* values as hidden fields.

```
<g:hiddenField name="min" value="0" />
<g:hiddenField name="max" value="20" />
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 2):

By the time that code hits the browser, it is just HTML.  `from` doesn't exist anymore. If that is being rendered into some sort of client side validation, that's not going to get submitted back to the server in a form submit.

If you explain what you are really needing to do in your question, I can provide a better answer.